# Preventing duplicate value in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage, object-oriented-database

I'm creating a library archive site containing a collection of my favorite reads. I have a click event listener on the books, adding them to my local storage key 'books' when doing so. I want it so that, if I click on the same book twice, it won't be added as a duplicate value in my ls. I've tried things I've found on here like an "if" statement checking the index of the new 'book' and comparing it to others, as well as filtering, but to no avail.

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(function(uibook){
  let arr = []
  for(i=0;i < uibook.length; i++){
    
    arr.push(uibook[i])
    console.log(arr)
    return arr
  }
  uibook.addEventListener('click',function(){
    window.document.location = './details.html'

    const title = uibook.innerText
    const summary = uibook.querySelector('.card-summary').innerText
    const genre = uibook.querySelector('.card-genre').innerText
    const author = uibook.querySelector('.card-author').innerText
    const page = uibook.querySelector('.card-page').innerText
    const img = uibook.querySelector('img.card-img-top').getAttribute('src');
  
    // Instantiate book
    const Nbook = new book(title,genre,author,page,summary,img);
    console.log(Nbook)

    if (localStorage.getItem('books') === null){
            books = [];
          }
          else{
            books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
          }
          books.push(Nbook)
          localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
          // localStorage.clear();

          add('lastKey',Nbook)
    
  })
})
  var lastKey;
  
function add(key,value) {
  lastKey = key;      
  console.log(value)              
  localStorage.setItem(lastKey, JSON.stringify(value));
}

////////////////DETAILS PAGE/////////////////////////

function getBooks(){
  // let lastKey;
  if(localStorage.getItem('lastKey') === null){
    lastKey = [];
  } else {
    lastKey = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastKey'));
  }
  console.log(lastKey)

//details info UI
  document.querySelector('.details-title').innerText = `${lastKey.title}`

  var imgTest = document.querySelector('.details-img').src = `${lastKey.img}`
 
  console.log(imgTest)

  document.querySelector('.summary-text').innerText = `${lastKey.summary}`
  document.querySelector('.genre-text').innerText = `${lastKey.genre}`
  console.log(document.querySelector('.author-text').innerText = `${lastKey.author}`)
  
  document.querySelector('.pageNum-text').innerText = `${lastKey.page}`
}
getBooks()
```

Edit: *updated the code* I should also add that I have 2 keys in my ls. One is the 'lastkey', which as you may have guessed just has the value of the last book that was clicked on. This is to output the details of the book on the following page. The 'book' key is to have all of the books that I click on w/o duplicates. The purpose is b/c I have a carousel at the bottom of the page where I want to output suggested books by their genre, and I don't want to have duplicates of the same books. knowwhatimean?

Comment: You have too many `})` at the end.

Comment: can you show the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: yea just updated

Answer (score 0):

To make comparison easy, you could have the `books` array be an array of JSON strings that you can compare with `===` or `.includes`:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('books') === null) {
  books = [];
} else {
  books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
}
const stringified = JSON.stringify(Nbook);
if (!books.includes(stringified)) {
  books.push(stringified);
}
localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
```

Then, when parsing books elsewhere, call `JSON.parse` on array items to get to the underlying object, eg

```
const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')).map(JSON.parse);
// console.log(book[0].title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Search your `books` array for another book with the same title.

```js
uibook.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.document.location = './details.html'

  const title = uibook.innerText

  if (localStorage.getItem('books') === null) {
    books = [];
  } else {
    books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
  }
  const foundBook = books.find(book => book.title == title);
  if (!foundBook) {
    // Instantiate book
    const summary = uibook.querySelector('.card-summary').innerText
    const genre = uibook.querySelector('.card-genre').innerText
    const author = uibook.querySelector('.card-author').innerText
    const page = uibook.querySelector('.card-page').innerText
    const img = uibook.querySelector('img.card-img-top').getAttribute('src');
    const Nbook = new book(title, genre, author, page, summary, img);
    books.push(Nbook);
    console.log(Nbook)
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
    add('lastKey', Nbook)
  } else {
    add('lastKey', foundBook);
  }

})
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot! Its nice and simple, only thing is when i put it in my code the 'book' key comes out as an empty array, i think its just updating the 'lastkey' but the lastkey only takes one book at a time. I want it to appear in my 'books'

Comment: Sorry, I left out `books.push(Nbook)`